How to create a collapsible toolbar when using Frame Layout that handles the Fragments
I have this in my activity_main file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"></include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Fragment"
        android:background="@drawable/border_menu_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:backgroundTint="#535087"
            android:contentDescription="Add Poll"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_poll"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" >




        </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/overlay"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">



        </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

This in my toolbar_layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/main_image_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"

                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="60dp"
                        android:layout_height="60dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"


                        ></ImageView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    android:weightSum="9"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:id="@+id/iconProfile"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true">

                        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                            app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
                            app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:gravity="center"


                        >


                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/login_logo_font"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="PollIt"
                            android:textSize="25dp"
                            android:textColor="#6D4C41">

                        </TextView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_weight="3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"

                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iconRefresh"
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:gravity="right"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_refresh"></ImageView>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                            android:id="@+id/iconSearch"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_width="38dp"
                            android:layout_height="38dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search"></ImageView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

And this in my follow_fragment layout where there is a RecyclerView:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#D7CCC8"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/followInterestsList"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</RelativeLayout>

I've been trying using the CollapsableToolbarLayout but find the resources confusing as my layouts are different to the resources I have looked at.
